# Elasticsearch - Not require an exact match

Tags: python, search, elasticsearch

Currently I have an item in my elasticsearch index with the title: `testing123`.

When I search for it, I can only get it returned if I search `testing123` exactly. However, I want to be able to search `testing` and have it returned too.

How can I have it so the search must start with that term but also not be an exact match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Simple Analyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/SimpleAnalyzer.html) in your mapping.

Create an index where the `title` field is indexed using the both the standard (default) and simple analyzers:

```
POST /demo
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "fields": {
                        "simple": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "simple"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index a document

```
POST /demo/doc/1
{
    "title": "testing123"
}
```

Finally, search using the `multi_match` query:

```
POST /demo/doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
                "title",
                "title.simple"
            ],
            "query": "testing"
        }
    }
}
```

This query returns the document. If you were to change the query term to `testing123` there would also be a match.

Another possible solution would be to use the [Prefix Query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're looking for [wildcards](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).

> Matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression. Supported wildcards are *, which matches any character sequence (including the empty one), and ?, which matches any single character.

Wildcards are basically a "match anything here". So your search would look like

```
testing*
```

which would match

> testing
>
> testing123
>
> testingthings

but would not match

> test123ing

or

> test

Comment: Whilst wildcards do achieve the correct result, I don't want the user to have to do this their end. Is there nothing built, as I believe solr had this.